# Block Shipping method getting executed in Cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

Is it possible to disable shipping method from getting executed in the cart page. We only want it to call it in the checkout process.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "executed in the cart page".

Comment: While in the cart page the CollectRates method of the Shipping method is called and rate is calculated. I want to stop this and only want to call the shipping method while checking out. I'm currently looking at the Mage_Checkout_CartController page but not sure from where the shipping method is getting called.

Comment: Have a look at the logic taking place within `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::save()`. However, even if you address your issue by doing a rewrite and preventing it from saving, I have a feeling that there are several other places where this takes place as well.

Comment: you don't want Estimate Shipping and Tax calculation on cart page?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. First, create an observer:

```
        <checkout_cart_save_before>
            <observers>
                <prevent_saving>
                    <class>mymodulename/observer</class>
                    <method>preventSaving</method>
                </prevent_saving>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_save_before>
```

Here is the observer function:

```
public function preventSaving(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
    if($cart instanceof Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart){
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();
        $quote->preventSaving();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: @nikhil did my answer work for you? if so, please accept, its been a while. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the question. I assume you want to remove the shipping calculations block from the cart page.

Open the file local.xml in your theme, and find the tag

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
```

And remove the block **checkout.cart.shipping** via `<remove name="left"/>`

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
   <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

**OR**

If you are using the checkout.xml directly in your theme then comment/remove  the below line

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```